# How can I read a file encoded in EUC-TW (not supported by SSIS) into SSIS as a flat file source?

Tags: csv, encoding, ssis

Does anyone know how to import a CSV file with unsupported encoding method into SSIS as a source?

I've tried to use Script Component to import, but end up noticing that it still needs to specify an encoding method which is supported by SSIS.

Comment: TIL - [EUC-TW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-TW) is a variable-length encoding that supports US-ASCII and 16 planes of CNS 11643, each of which is 94x94. It is a rarely used encoding for traditional Chinese characters

Comment: @billinkc Unfortunately, due to job requirements I have to use this super rare encoding as a source. I'm curious about if there is a way to read files without knowing it's encoding names. Such as reading as bytes or something else...

Comment: Disclaimer, I'm a dumb murican with only 1 language but I do lots of stuff with SSIS. So EUC-TW is still a 7 bit language encoding but instead of 65 being `A` as it is in ASCII it'd be the first character of your gravatar? You need to do something like that? And yes, you can set up a Script Source to read a file as bytes and then interpret them as needed to push them into the pipeline. Happy to help with what I can from an SSIS perspective

Comment: @billinkc Thanks a lot for your kind help! I'm going to try the method you told me. I'll let you know if my problem is solved!